# Firebase Custom Events passing in Debug view, but not showing up in Events Analytics

Tags: firebase, nativescript, firebase-analytics

I'm an analyst and our team is working with a developer team to get some new custom events passed to our mobile app. We already have our app live and running with 50 events firing just fine. We are currently testing out some new custom events in the app and see it passing through in the debug view in Firebase.

However when we go to the "Events" in the Analytics Section of Firebase it is not showing up. It's already been 2 days of testing and none of the new events we tested and saw fire in debug view are showing up in the "Events" section. Any thoughts as to why it's not showing up? I'm even seeing revenue data pass through on Google Analytics, but still no purchase event hits.

I'm not a developer and based on my research it should be passing through if it's firing in debug mode unless there is something I'm missing.

***Update, I'm seeing data in BigQuery for my new events, but still not on Firebase. Is it just a timing thing? It's data from 1-2 days ago that was tested. ***

Comment: I have exactly the same problem: I can see the data in Debug View and in Bigquery, but nothing in the Events section in Firebase console.

Comment: Did you find the problem? I am in the same situation